# React and Bootstrap with react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I've seen two different ways to use Bootstraps Form.Control. For example a text input.

Method 1 using the Controller

```
const schema = yup.object().shape({
    login: yup.string().required('Email address is required')
});


<Controller
control={control}
name="login"
defaultValue=""
render={
({ field: { onChange, value, ref } }) => (
      <Form.Control onChange={onChange} value={value} ref={ref} 
isInvalid={errors?.login} placeholder="Enter user name" />
  )
}/>
```

Method 2 using register

```
const schema = yup.object().shape({
    login: yup.string().required('Email address is required')
});


<Form.Control {...register('login')} name="login" type="text" placeholder="Enter email" />
```

So my question is, why use a Controller? Is Bootstrap Form.Control a controlled or un-controlled component?

From [Bootstrap website](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/forms/overview/):

The  component directly renders the  or other specified component. If you need to access the value of an uncontrolled , attach a ref to it as you would with an uncontrolled input, then call ReactDOM.findDOMNode(ref) to get the DOM node.

**Update 11/10**

I think I found my answer from the react-hook-form site and that is if there is no ref support, use a Controller:

React Hook Form has made it easy to integrate with external UI component libraries. If the component doesn't expose input's ref, then you should use the Controller component, which will take care of the registration process.

Comment: Your update solved the problem for me, thank you very much!!! +1